# NSMutableArray is null even after pushing array inside it

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

Hope you could help me, my trouble is the following one:

- I have a NSMutableArray which is empty.
- One of my methods is fetching a SQLite DB (using FMDB Framework) and pushing all the values in the column "name" into the NSMutable array.
- But when I am displaying the NSMutableArray (or any value of this array), it's defined as null

Most of similar question are due to the "area" where the array is available (not global but local) but not in this case (I don't think so).

I have no warning and no error from xCode.

Here's a part of my code:

**.h file**
    #import

```
@interface MasterViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, assign) int nbUsers;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSMutableArray *nameOfUsers;

@end
```

**viewDidLoad method**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

    // Number of users
    int tempNb = 0;
    NSArray *docPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [docPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *dbPath = [documentsDir   stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"UserDatabase.sqlite"];

    FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:dbPath];

    [...]

    // Name of users
    [database open];
    int i = 0;
    FMResultSet *results2 = [database executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM userList"];
    while ([results2 next]) {
        [_nameOfUsers insertObject:[results2 stringForColumn:@"name"] atIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"%@", _nameOfUsers[i]);
        i++;
        //[_nameOfUsers addObject:(NSString *)[results2 stringForColumn:@"name"]];
    }
    [database close];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(insertNewObject:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
}
```

What I want to do is to display these name into my cells in the master view via:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myBasicCell"];
    cell.textLabel.text = _nameOfUsers[indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"%D and the name is %@", indexPath.row, _nameOfUsers[indexPath.row]);
    return cell;
}
```

But the trouble is not here, since by using NSLog, I found that my SQLite DB is well filled, the value fetched are validated too, it's the NSMutableArray which is not filled properly (maybe the method I am using for filling it is not good, but I followed many similar question which describe the same method).

Thank you in advance for your time,

Sincerely,

Comment: where do you initialize/create it?

Comment: Forget nameOfUsers allocation.

Comment: The `nameOfUsers` property should not be `assign`, it should be `strong`. And as mentioned, you never initialize `_nameOfUsers`.

Comment: Thank you for these fast answer, I forgot to mention them but I am @synthesizing the nameOfUsers in my .m file.

I also tried at first with strong property at nameOfUsers (I changed it just fo try and forgot to replace it, thank you) but it changed nothing.

Comment: Synthesizing a property has nothing at all to do with initializing it's value.

Comment: Thank you rmaddy, this is what I didn't understood about synthesyze.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ARC project:
    @interface MasterViewController : UITableViewController

```
@property (nonatomic, readWrite) int nbUsers;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *nameOfUsers;

@end
```

Non ARC:

```
@interface MasterViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, readWrite) int nbUsers;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *nameOfUsers;

@end
```

and in viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _nameOfUsers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    // Number of users
    int tempNb = 0;
    NSArray *docPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [docPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *dbPath = [documentsDir   stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"UserDatabase.sqlite"];

    FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:dbPath];

    [...]

    // Name of users
    [database open];
    int i = 0;
    FMResultSet *results2 = [database executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM userList"];
    while ([results2 next]) {
        [_nameOfUsers insertObject:[results2 stringForColumn:@"name"] atIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"%@", _nameOfUsers[i]);
        i++;
        //[_nameOfUsers addObject:(NSString *)[results2 stringForColumn:@"name"]];
    }
    [database close];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(insertNewObject:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I didn't noticed that synthesysing a property had nothing to do with init it, thank to all the answer I now understood it. 

I'm new in iOS and I was just unable to find this trouble by myself since I went in the wrong way at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSMutableArray *nameOfUsers;it should be retain or strong(if you use ARC), and you never init nameOfUsers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, as I mentioned in the previous comments, I synthsized my nameOfUsers in my .m file. Moreover, my nameOfUsers was also defined as "strong" (I changed it in one of the many try to resolve this trouble and totally forgot to replace it, thank you)